# I am geeting error while Installing cucumber eclipse plugin 1.0.0 from market place

Tags: java, eclipse, cucumber, window, gherkin

[image]I'm looking for Natural plugin. but doesn't found so insteade of try to installing Cucumber eclipse plugins.

so for installing  "Cucumber Eclipse" plugin.so search for "Cucumber" in eclipse market place, and it would appear in the top of the list.

also try In Eclipse, in "Help" >> "Install New Software...",

An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=C__Users_Ankit_eclipse_java-2021-09_eclipse, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Result of processing steps.
OK
OK
OK
Public key not found for -9147676190077153272.
OK
Result of processing steps.
OK
OK
OK
Public key not found for -9147676190077153272.
OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use marketplace, but instead install the offline zip package from [here](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-eclipse). I'm running it in Eclipse 2020-09 with no problem.

Comment: Hi ou

Thanks! I have downloaded the zipfile from above but unable to load in ecilipse could you please suggest me the steps to implemet it on my ecilipse.

Comment: Help -> Software update -> Add Site -> Archive -> Install