Installing software has ecountered a problem . An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
I wanted to install the darkest dark theme from eclipse marketplace but I have this error:
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=C__Users_carug_eclipse_java-2020-09_eclipse, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Result of processing steps.
OK
OK
OK
Public key not found for 6640597757109451687.
OK
Result of processing steps.
OK
OK
Public key not found for 6640597757109451687.
OK
Result of processing steps.
OK
OK
OK
Public key not found for 6640597757109451687.
OK
Result of processing steps.
OK
OK
Public key not found for 6640597757109451687.
OK
Result of processing steps.
OK
OK
Public key not found for 6640597757109451687.
OK
Result of processing steps.
OK
OK
Public key not found for 510852041806296410.
OK
Result of processing steps.
OK
OK
Public key not found for -8587782299385769255.
OK
Does anyone have any idea how to solve it?
Thanks in advance.
I don't know, I have tried to launch eclipse as administrator.

Eclipse has a standard dark theme which seems fine to me without having to install anything.

2020-09 is approaching 4 years old, and might not support the newer jar signing mechanisms that have been adopted in the past two years.

By the way, the dark theme you want to install patches Eclipse via loadtime weaving which can cause issues and slow down Eclipse (the vendor of this plugin tries to cheat the open source license of Eclipse by doing so). If you don't like the built-in themes, there are other dark themes that are more ergonomic and don't do this.

A related ones https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75816317 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75343481. And a similar one is in Eclipse 4.21.0 in my case.

org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPPublicKey found where PGPPublicKeyRing expected. on error log it proceeded to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75760149/how-to-resolve-public-key-error-while-installing-efx-3-8-0-eclipse-plugin-on-l

Notably there is a related OS class to previous ones. APSCertificateManager.
